# Sass loader can't load url with Encore webpack and Symfony 5

Tags: symfony, sass-loader, webpack-encore

I updated Encore webpack and its dependencies. Since, I have this error :

> Error: Can't resolve
> '/fonts/Basier-Circle-medium-webfont/basiercircle-medium-webfont.woff'
> in 'E:\Projets web\Roadtripr\roadtripr\assets\css'
> at runMicrotasks ()

The font-files are in the `public/fonts` directory.

EDIT :

There is the @font-face declaration :

```
/* Basier */
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Basier';
  src: url('/fonts/Basier-Circle-regular-webfont/basiercircle-regular-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
       url('/fonts/Basier-Circle-regular-webfont/basiercircle-regular-webfont.woff2') format('woff2');
  font-weight: 100;
  font-style: normal;
}
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Basier';
  src: url('/fonts/Basier-Circle-regular-webfont/basiercircle-regular-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
       url('/fonts/Basier-Circle-regular-webfont/basiercircle-regular-webfont.woff2') format('woff2');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Basier';
  src: url('/fonts/Basier-Circle-medium-webfont/basiercircle-medium-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
       url('/fonts/Basier-Circle-medium-webfont/basiercircle-medium-webfont.woff2') format('woff2');
  font-weight: 300;
  font-style: normal;
}
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Basier';
  src: url('/fonts/Basier-Circle-semibold-webfont/basiercircle-semibold-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
       url('/fonts/Basier-Circle-semibold-webfont/basiercircle-semibold-webfont.woff2') format('woff2');
  font-weight: 500;
  font-style: normal;
}
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Basier';
  src: url('/fonts/Basier-Circle-bold-webfont/basiercircle-bold-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
       url('/fonts/Basier-Circle-bold-webfont/basiercircle-bold-webfont.woff2') format('woff2');
  font-weight: 700;
  font-style: normal;
}
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Basier';
  src: url('/fonts/Basier-Circle-bold-webfont/basiercircle-bold-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
       url('/fonts/Basier-Circle-bold-webfont/basiercircle-bold-webfont.woff2') format('woff2');
  font-weight: bold;
  font-style: normal;
}
```

Comment: Error: Can't resolve '/fonts/Basier-Circle-regular-webfont/basiercircle-regular-webfont.woff2' in 'E:\Projets web\Roadtripr\roadtripr\assets\css'
    at runMicrotasks (<anonymous>)

Answer (score 1):

Do not put your your font files in your `public` directory.

Put them in `assets/fonts`. Picture something like this:

```
E:\Projets web\Roadtripr\roadtripr
|- bin/
|- config/
|- assets/
|    |- css/
|    |- fonts/
|- src/
|- public/
```

When you run `yarn encore` the file fonts referenced by `url()` declarations will be copied to your `public/build` directory automatically.

Comment: Thank your very much for your help. I moved the folder "fonts' from 'public' to 'asset'. I ran  Encore webpack : the files were copied to public/build. However, I always have the same error.

Comment: Sorry I made a mistake. Files were not copied to public / build / fonts when starting Encore webpack

Comment: I modified the Encore webpack configuration file and the files were now correctly copied to the public/build/fonts folder. However, I always have the same error.

Comment: Yeah, something doesn't add up. I've asked something else below the question, though.

Comment: Sorry, I hadn't seen the question. According to me, the console gives me the first error encountered, but it must be the same for all lines.

Comment: Indeed, if I remove some lines, the error appears on the first : Error: Can't resolve '/fonts/Basier-Circle-semibold-webfont/basiercircle-semibold-webfont.woff' in 'E:\Projets web\Roadtripr\roadtripr\assets\css'
    at runMicrotasks (<anonymous>)

Answer (score 0):

maybe a little bit late
but I faced the same problem and fixed it by moving the fonts files into assets/css folder (same folder as your CSS file)
and changed the path inside the CSS file from url ("/fonts/....") to url ("nameoffolder")

Answer (score 0):

put your font file into :

`/assets/fonts/your-font.ttf`

then into /assets/scss/your-style.scss:

```
@font-face{
    font-family : 'your-font';
    src : url('../fonts/your-font.ttf') format('truetype');
}
```

webpack will do the job